# Trouble with JDK on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, java-8, webstorm

I have `Mac OS X 10.13.6`. Previously I had the official `JDK 8` installed which used to work fine but recently I switched to the `Homebrew` version and also upgraded to `JDK 10`. This has suddenly broken my java setup. Now when I try to launch `Webstorm` I get the following error:

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.a(PluginManager.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.a(PluginManager.java:75)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt.dylib: dlopen(/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt.dylib
  Reason: image not found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1673)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateFrameClass(AppUIUtil.java:155)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.a(MainImpl.java)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:43)
    ... 6 more
```

The folder `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/` is not there and I can't find any instructions online on how to install it. I tried installing `Oracle JDK 8` from the official binaries again but the installation fails with no details. I managed to install `Oracle JDK 10` from the official binaries but the folder still isn't there. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem isn't `JAVA_HOME`. It appears `JavaVM.framework` comes with `MacOS` and is not bundled with `Oracle JDK`. I need a way to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/488757/deleted-javavm-framework-how-to-restore) post that lead me to the solution. I used [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com) to extract `JavaVM.framework` from the `High Sierra` install dmg.